# What is the difference between the wiper motor and the wiper motor control? Caddilac CTS 2006

Tags: parts

What is the difference between the wiper motor and the wiper motor control? Does the wiper motor control work the relay switch, in other words if your wipers wont shut off is that a wiper motor control problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have the problem described [here](http://www.cadillacforums.com/forums/cadillac-cts-first-generation-forum-2003/195546-wiper-motor-has-own-mind-2004-a.html).  Indications are replacing the motor is a fix.  [This](http://www.cadillacforums.com/forums/cadillac-cts-first-generation-forum-2003/149036-wipers-will-not-turn-off.html) indicates there is some sort of module on the back of the motor, that might be what is actually broke.

Not sure how this works, I'd have to see a wiring diagram.  Power to the wiper motor is going to be going through a relay, but as far as what can cause that relay to engage, you'd need a diagram or trace the wiring.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a problem in which the wipers would not turn off when I told them to. The fix involved replacing the motor itself, not some sort of external control system or relay. I took the old motor apart, and it definitely seems that there is an embedded control mechanism, which explains the necessity of replacing the whole motor. I found this preferable, however, to tearing apart my dash to replace something in there.